# LWC display image attached to custom record

Tags: lightning-web-components, files, images

I want to show a photo, like an Id photo that is attached to a custom record. I've tried notes and attachments as well as files to upload the photo file. I need to show the photo in an lwc. I've tried using the img tag with some various ways to retrieve the attached photo with no luck yet. . .

js:

```
@wire(getIdPhoto, { evaluatorId : '$evaluatorId' })
idPhotoDetails({ data, error }){
    if(data){
        this.idPhoto = data;
        this.photoUrl = data[0].VersionDataUrl+ '?thumb=THUMB240BY180'; 
        console.log('this.idPhoto ----- ', this.idPhoto);

    }else if(error){
        console.log('ERROR ----- ', JSON.stringify(error));

    }
}
```

apex:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static list<ContentVersion> relatedFiles(String evaluatorId){
    list<id> lstConDocs = new list<id>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink cntLink : [Select Id, ContentDocumentId From ContentDocumentLink Where LinkedEntityId = :evaluatorId]) {
        lstConDocs.add(cntLink.ContentDocumentId);
    }
    if(!lstConDocs.isEmpty()) {
        return [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId, VersionDataURL, ContentUrl FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :lstConDocs];
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="slds-grid" >
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12">
                    <img src={photoUurl} height="100px" width="100px"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Is this a viable approach? (currently I just get an empty image100px by 100px) or is there a better way?

console:

```
this.idPhoto -----  
Object { Id: "0683S000001fTk1QAE", Title: "placeholder id photo", ContentDocumentId: "0693S000001fZoIQAU", ContentSize: "7666", VersionDataUrl: "https://caloes--sap.sandbox.my.site.com/sap/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0683S000001fTk1" }
​
ContentDocumentId: "0693S000001fZoIQAU"
​
ContentSize: "7666"
​
Id: "0683S000001fTk1QAE"
​
Title: "placeholder id photo"
​
VersionDataUrl: "https://xxxxxx--sap.sandbox.my.site.com/sap/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0683S000001fTk1"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
sapViewEvaluatorBadge.js:1:3846
this.photoUrl -----  https://xxxxxx--sap.sandbox.my.site.com/sap/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0683S000001fTk1?thumb=THUMB240BY180
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the photo in base64 and use that data in the `src` attribute.
The `src` attribute can hold a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) in format `data:[<mediatype>][;charset=<character set>][;base64]`.

- The mediatype is a MIME type string, such as `image/jpeg` for a JPEG image file, that's why I'm going to retrieve the File Extension from ContentDocument.
- You could use [EncodingUtil.base64Encode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_base64Encode) to encode the blob of the photo and since it outputs an `utf-8` string, that will be the charset.

You need a single SOQL since from ContentDocumentLink you could go up to ContentVersion. Moreover I added `LIMIT 1` since you only use the first file.

**APEX**:

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String relatedFiles(Id evaluatorId){
    List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = [SELECT ContentDocument.FileExtension, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData
                FROM ContentDocumentLink
                WHERE LinkedEntityId = :evaluatorId
                LIMIT 1];

    String base64Data;
    if(!contentDocumentLinks.isEmpty()) {
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = contentDocumentLinks[0];
        base64Data = 'data:image/' + cdl.ContentDocument.FileExtension + ';charset=utf-8;base64, ';
        base64Data += EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cdl.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData);
    }
    return base64Data;
}
```

**JS**:

```js
@wire(getIdPhoto, { evaluatorId : '$evaluatorId' })
idPhotoDetails({ data, error }){
    if (data) {
        this.photoUrl = data; 
     }else if(error){
        console.log('ERROR ----- ', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="slds-grid" >
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12">
        <img src={photoUurl} height="100" width="100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that `height` and [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#width) are always in pixel and must hold an integer without a unit, so `100` instead of `100px`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this, but your URL is incorrect.

You want something like: `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId={yourContentVersionId}`

This won't work in an unauthenticated site.  The previews don't work there.

Comment: `https://xxxxxx--sap.sandbox.my.site.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=0683S000001fTk1QAE`   **still no photo :(

Comment: @mackmama does it work in salesforce? (not in a site?)

Comment: in Site, no. Internally. . . not sure. having other issues there. I'll update if I figure it out